# Catching Flash URLLoader errors

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5, urlloader

I'm trying to bullet proof a URLLoader and wondering where I need to capture things like 404s and more importantly, mid-session timeouts and connectivity failures.

The app will be run in places where the connectivity is spotty and it is very possible that a connection will initiate correctly, but will die somewhere in the middle.  I'm unable to recreate these scenarios in testing and am hoping someone can point me to a comprehensive list of error handling, so that I can anticipate most of the common network failures and handle them.

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to handle the `ioError` and `securityError` events - that will catch all the errors. Timeouts will just eventually produce an ioError.

You might also want to listen to the `httpStatus` event to get the HTTP code.